# how to convert integer field to date in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report designed in iReport with an integer field and it is displaying like:

*End date*

```
20171022
20170906
20170903
```

but I need to show this field in date format like:

```
22/10/2017
06/09/2017
03/09/2017
```

The *20171022* value at DB means the *22 October of 2017* date

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `20171022` - Are you sure that it is Integer, not the String?

Comment: You can use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @AlexK yes, the field is an integer.

Comment: I tried the answers in the other questions but some of them give an error: `The method X is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)` or give me a wrong date in the year 1970. This is the first time I'm using iReport, maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: If you are storing the "22 November of 2017 year" date as Integer with 20171022 value - it is very unusual approach. If yes - I will remove duplicate flag, because in this case the solutions described at links are not working. Ping me in this case

Comment: Yes, I don't know the reason but the value is storing like that: 20171022 for "22 October of 2017"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below expression to achieve your desired result.

```
$F{column_name}.toString().substring(6,8) + "/" + $F{column_name}.toString().substring(4,6) + "/" + $F{column_name}.toString().substring(0,4)
```

You can handle the same inside your query. You just have to convert above expression as per your selected database.

Comment: I can't modify the original query. I tried almost every answer in the other questions but this was the only thing that work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Dayana Glad to help you.